# How to load ng-src depending on value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got a `dropdown` with a list of names of images. Selecting an image will load and display it using `ng-src directive`. Everything works fine when a value is selected.

However, the `dropdow` contains also an `empty value`. When selected, the `ng-src` event is fired and tries to get the image with an empty name.

This fires a 404 error, since the ressource doesn't exist and can't be found by the server.

```
GET http://..../api/images/logo/ 404 (Not Found)
```

Question is: how can I prevent the loading event when the value selected is empty ?

Comment: bind to a separate value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, using an `ng-if` solved the problem as it removes the `img tag` from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition to ng-src to display a default image if no image was selected. something similar to this:

```
<img ng-src="{{ image || 'default-image.jpg' }}" />
```

Comment: I don't want to display any image at all

Comment: You can make defailt-image a blank image, so that nothing will be displayed to the user

Comment: Already did, the tag is: `<img ng-show="context.logo" ng-src="{{apiUrl}}/api/images/logo/{{context.logo}}">`. The event is still fired.

Comment: Actually, I didn't try the `ng-if` and it works using it, event isn't fired. Didn't know there was a difference between `ng-if` and `ng-show` though. Thanks for your concern :)